# Calculating Age Sql query

Tags: php, mysql

good day guys i have my code here to get age from date of birth stored in my database.

```
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("mydb",$connect);

$query = "select date_format(now(), '%Y') - date_format(dob, '%Y') - (date_format(now(), '00-%m-%d') < date_format(dob, '00-%m-%d'))
as age from data";
$result = mysql_query($query); 
$values = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$age = $values['age']; 

$query="select * from data";
$result=mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
echo "<table align='center' border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>id</th>";
echo "<th>Last Name</th>";
echo "<th>First Name</th>";
echo "<th>Age</th>";
echo "</tr>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['lname']."</td>";  
echo "<td>".$row['fname']."</td>";  
echo "<td>".$age."</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
```

all data is fetch but the only problem is the age of the first row is the same as the rest of my data. what wrong with my code? anybody help please thank you.

Comment: run your query in phpmyadmin what you get? getting age?

Comment: query return age in terms of year ... may be first two record might be same

Comment: Can you show some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: You are getting age of the last record only, and assigning that age to all the records,

Comment: Pramod is right. Try $row['age'] instead of $age in your while loop

Comment: i tried it in phpmyadmin it returns the age exactly @RakeshSharma

Comment: this is the date of birth of the first row, 2014-12-01 it is stored as datetime format.. and returns 0 for the first until the last row of my data @Jens

Comment: Have you tried solutions given below ?

Comment: @KimTirania Can you explain this part `(date_format(now(), '00-%m-%d') < date_format(dob, '00-%m-%d'))` of your query? Think that is wrong.

Comment: i tried of all it and does'nt work for me. @Pramod

Comment: @KimTirania, see my modified answer

Answer (score 0):

You are printing pre-fetched age from values array.
Instead read from current row and use to display.

Change your SQL query as below:

```
$query = "select id, lname, fname, 
              date_format(now(), '%Y') - date_format(dob, '%Y') 
            - (   date_format(now(), '00-%m-%d') 
                < date_format(dob, '00-%m-%d'))
            as age
          from data";
```

**Change**:

```
echo "<td>".$age."</td>";
```

**To**:

```
echo "<td>".$row['age']."</td>";
```

Comment: it does'nt work . the same as before, and when it says undefined index age.

Comment: In your code, replace `$query="select * from data";` with the query I suggested.

Comment: it returns 0 in all of the value when i replace your query @Ravinder

Comment: @KimTirania: You better post some records from the table. Include the columns `id`, `lname`, `fname`, `dob`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are fetching the age for single time, get the dob in while loop and then calculate the age and print the age in while loop itself.

Comment: i think it is. i get it for a single time and it display for the entire row.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your age formula is right, try this query.

```
// query will give all records and age for each record.
    $query="SELECT a.*, (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dob,NOW()) FROM data AS b WHERE a.id = b.id) AS age FROM data AS a";

// rather than getting two result sets, you have age in the same record now, access it as a field.
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    echo "<table align='center' border='1'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>id</th>";
    echo "<th>Last Name</th>";
    echo "<th>First Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Age</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['lname']."</td>";  
    echo "<td>".$row['fname']."</td>";  
    echo "<td>".$row['age']."</td>"; // get age from db results

    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    }
```

Comment: i got this error in your code,     Warning: mysql_query(): Unable to save result set in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\crud\index.php on line 14

    Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\crud\index.php on line 15

Comment: @KimTirania, I have modified the query and tested it, this will work for you.

Comment: @KimTirania, use this query - "SELECT a.*, (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dob,NOW()) FROM data AS b WHERE a.id = b.id) AS age FROM data AS a";

Answer (score 0):

You are getting age once and using it for rest of your data.
Try something like this:

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("mydb", $connect);
$query = "select * from data";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "<table align='center' border='1'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>id</th>";
    echo "<th>Last Name</th>";
    echo "<th>First Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Age</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $query1 = "select date_format(now(), '%Y') - date_format(dob, '%Y') - (date_format(now(), '00-%m-%d') < date_format(dob, '00-%m-%d'))
as age from data where id = $row[id]";
        $result1 = mysql_query($query);
        $values1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $age = $values1['age'];

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['lname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['fname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $age . "</td>";

        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: it only returns the first row in my database and the age is correct @RahulShandilya